# Kafka server contains messages but consumer cannot receive any(producer used compression.type=snappy)

Tags: compression, apache-kafka, consumer, snappy

I am a newbie in `Kafka`.When using kafka 0.9.0, I can set a codec by setting the `compression.type` property of my kafka producer.

Suppose I use `snappy` compression in my producer, when consuming the messages from kafka using some kafka-consumer, should I do something to *decode the data* from snappy or is it some built-in feature of kafka consumer?

In the office doc, I could not find any property that relates to encoding in kafka consumer (it only relates to the producer).

Can someone clear this?

Answer (score 0):

`As mentioned in their wiki Page,there is no need for any decompression logic on the Consumer side`:

**Please have a look at their wiki page below:**

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Compression

The data received by a consumer for a topic might contain both compressed as well as uncompressed messages. The `consumer` iterator `transparently` `decompresses compressed` data and only returns an `uncompressed message`.

Comment: Thanks, I got it.But I cannot received the message which compressed. Do you known the reason? Thanks in advance.